# How to push existing/created/instantiated class object to be used on Lua script?

Tags: c++, lua

Most binding libs/packages let pretty clear how to expose a class TYPE so that it can be created on a Lua script.

What Im having REALLY difficulties with, is how give to a Lua script an already created/instantiated/allocated class object, so that you can then, call its exposed/binded methods from the Lua script (updating the object also in the c++ side)..

If this is still not clear, I will give the real example that is what I have right now.

Im using [Lunar](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CppBindingWithLunar) to expose my AIAgent class methods to Lua. **Its working**, I can **create** AIAgents on the Lua script..But who cares, Im not programming on Lua, Im using Lua to script my AI agents, part of my game engine, created by my game engine, update/collision detection and response/drawing is all done by the c++ code, the only thing the script is supposed to do is give the agent the decision making code (a lua coroutine called on the agent update method ). This decision make script have access to some registered (trough Lunar) methods (GetHP, GetNAmmunition, GetPlayerPos, etc.. )

So, how can I give the script my object?..Something like that:

```
//-fake code- called on the AIAgent constructor, or something
lua_pushObject( luaState, this );
lua_setGlobal( "aiAgentFromC++", -1 ); // object exposed trough "aiAgentFromC++" global var
```

Note that the methods are already exposed because I can create new objects on the scripts, I just dont know how to give the script an object I already have on the c++ side.

Comment: Have you considered switching to a Lua binding system that has a *website*? Or a manual? Or some kind of actual documentation outside of some bits of poorly-explained example code? I couldn't find anything online for "Lunar". SWIG, Lua++, LuaBind, etc, these are all out there with real documentation. Lunar is not.

Comment: LuaBind is slow, said by a dude I respect here on StackOverflow;SWIG seems incredible complicated, Im looking for lightweight packages, if you can recommend me one, Id be really happy..I though Lunar was fine, since I got it working fast, till I hit a wall..

Answer (score 2):

[LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge) is in my opinion the easiest way. It's also lightweight and dependency-free. You're saying:

> What Im having REALLY difficulties with, is how give to a Lua script
>   an already created/instantiated/allocated class object

It does exactly that

A sample:
C++

```
class A {
public:
    void print(int x) {
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    }
};

RefCountedPtr<A> GiveMeA()
{
    static RefCountedPtr<A> a(new A);
    return a;
}

int main() 
{
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    int s = luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua");

    luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
        .beginClass<A>("A")
        .addConstructor<void (*)()>()
        .addFunction("print",&A::print)
        .endClass()
        .addFunction("GiveMeA",&GiveMeA);

    if ( s==0 ) {
        s = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    }
    report_errors(L, s);
    lua_close(L);
}
```

in Lua:

```
local a=A()
a:print(42)
local b=GiveMeA() --created on the C++ side
b:print(42)
```

Comment: wheres exactly in the code you are instantiating an A object and giving to lua? local a = A() is a new object..its exactly what I said on my first paragraph, and its exactly NOT what I want...

Comment: How are you going to identify your objects? You could bind an interface and provide a factory function that would give you instances that you've created on the C++ side. But you have to know which object you want. Example pending ...

Comment: I gave my entire situation on the first post, the aiagent, created by the engine, then I gave an example (-fake code-)on how Id expose it trough lua_setGlobal( "aiAgentFromC++", -1 );, giving the this pointer, how can I be more clear than that?

Comment: Check out the updated code. You can manage your C++ anyway you like. Just provide a method to identify them if you need many of those, like using strings, or whatever.

Comment: there you go =D, now its it, Im going to try LuaBridge! Im marking as answer, even if I didnt tried it yet, I dont think theres can be any mistake..I hope

Comment: `aiAgentFromC++` is not a valid Lua identifier anyway, but you could wrap your "agent" like in the luabridge example, and then, give a reference to that in exactly the same fashion

Comment: @NicolBolas: it is as LuaBridge manual says "a non intrusive reference counted pointer...This is especially useful when the classes to be registered come from a third party library and cannot be modified. To use it, simply wrap all pointers to class objects with the container instead"

Comment: aiAgentFromC++ would be a new global variable identifier in the luastate, it would be the KEY, and the value would be the one at the top of the stack (the this pointer) (basically, create a global var and assign it the this pointer)

Comment: @Icebone1000: the ++ in the name is not a valid identifier